# How to detect camera orientation for correct drawing finish image in liveview?

Tags: camera, orientation, autofocus, edsdk

How can I:

1. Detect camera orientation in live view mode?
2. Set autofocus to on taken image?
3. Detect situation, when to set autofocus had failed

I am using EDSDK 2.10 and a Canon EOS 500D camera.